# Is there any way how to distribute constructor to two files?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on data core of application. I need to construct a few collections in one namespace like this:

```
var Core = function(){
   this.firstCollection = [];
   $.extend(true, this.firstCollection,{
      method1: function(){
         alert("working with firstCollection");
      }
};
var core = new Core();
```

Is there any elegant way, how to distribute the constructor into separated files for better maintenance? I want to use a pure JavaScript, no compiled one such Coffee/Dart.

Distribute into separated files means workaround like this:
file1:

```
var obj = obj||{};
obj.firstAttribute = "first";
```

file2

```
var obj = obj||{};
obj.secondAttribute = "second";
```

Comment: "distribute the constructor into separated files" that statement isint clear...

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? It could lead to different answers.

Comment: I want to search faster in file during development. I don't want to lose the possibility add a module later.

Comment: This would be a good use of AMD, such as with RequireJS - http://requirejs.org/.

Comment: Require.js seems to be over engineered for an application of my size. Generally it isn't elegant way. Also module architecture of jqueryui is a little big solution.

Comment: Put the constructor in a separate file then I guess.